# Create quizz form symfony

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to make a quizz in symfony but I'm having hard time with the rendering.

Here is my database :

[image: Databse]

A sequence (quizz), can have many questions, those questions have multiple answers and a user can choose one answer.

But the way it is build, I don't know how to create a simple form, so when a user will choose a answer it will update that user.
Simple twig rendering :

[image: Twig render]

Here is the view code (i've deleted some html) :

```
{% for sequence in enquete.sequences %}
{% for questseq in sequence.QuestionsSequence %}

<input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="{{questseq.Intitule}}" class="form-control input-md">

<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Réponses :</label>
   {% for repseq in questseq.ReponsesQuestion %}
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkboxes-{{repseq.id}}">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-{{repseq.id}}" value="1">
      {{ repseq.Intitule }}
     {%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
{%endfor%}
```

I know this is not the way to do it, I should create a Form and send it to the view right ?

Comment: "I know this is not the right thing to do". Why? What's wrong with it from your point of view? Also there's no code here that anyone can help you to fix. Screenshots only tell a small part of the story.

Comment: can you add some more information how your form (classes) and views look like?

Comment: @lordrhodos I've edited a bit, you want me to add some information about my forms ?

Comment: I think the more useful information you add the easier it is to get an answer ;-) Would be interesting to get to know more about your goals, etc. are the answers always going to be multi select checkboxes or will there be different question / answer types?

Comment: @lordrhodos, those question will have multiple answer but the user will only choose one (i know how to do that). 

My main issue is to have a form with the Question, Answers, and a submit button to add the selected answer to the answer's collection of the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know this is not the way to do it, I should create a Form and send it to the view right ?

this depends highly on your point of view. [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#building-forms) recommend to define your forms as PHP classes, but to get there in this scenario is not plain easy.

In one of my projects creating a [MOOC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_Open_Online_Course) in the past I was facing a similar task: show a quiz at the end of each module with multiple questions with only one answer type (radio buttons). I've implemented the following entities - *which can be mapped to your entities*:

- `Quiz` (sequence)
- `Question` (question_sequence)
- `Answer` (response_sequence)
- `UserQuizAnswer` (response_sequence_utilisateur)
- `UserQuizResult`
- `User` (utilisateur)

In addition to the persisted entities I have created to **not mapped** classes `UserQuizAnswerEvaluation` and `UserQuizEvaluation` because I needed to check weather the user reached a certain threshold (80%) of correct answers to pass the quiz.

My solution at that time (the quickest, not the best) was to pass the quiz object from the controller to the twig view and render the form without any [Form Classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-creating-form-classes):

```
# src/AppBundle/Controller/QuizController.php
public function showAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $quiz = $this->get('app.quiz.manager')->findQuizById($id);
    if (!$quiz) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    $viewParams = ['quiz' => $quiz];

    ...

    return $this->render(
      'AppBundle:quiz:show.html.twig',
        $viewParams
    );
}
```

In the view I iterate over the `questions` for the `Quiz`, display the question text and iterate over the `answers` for each `Question`, so pretty much the same what you are doing.

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/quiz/show.html.twig
<form action="{{ path('quiz_evaluate', {'id': quiz.id}) }}" method="post">

    {% for question in quiz.questions %}

    <div class="content-element">
        <p>{{ loop.index }}. {{ question.text }}</p>
        {% for answer in question.answers %}

            {% if evaluation is defined %}
                {% if (answer.id == evaluation.answers[question.id].answerId) %}
                    {% set checked = 'checked' %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set checked = '' %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ question.id }}]" value="{{ answer.id }}"
                            {% if checked is defined %}{{ checked }}{% endif %} >
                    <span class="upper">{{ loop.index|numberToAlphabet }}.</span> {{ answer.text }}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% if evaluation is defined %}
    <br>
        {% if evaluation.answers[question.id].isCorrect %}
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-check"> Success</i></h3>
        {% else %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Almost, please try again</h3>
        {% endif %}
                {{ question.answerDescription }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

        <div class="divider"></div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_PRE_SURVEY_COMPLETED') %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-enroll btn-block" value="Submit your answers">
</form>
```

However, if I would go to build something like this again, I would try to follow the best practices and define form classes for it. I would use the entity `UserQuizAnswer` and `UserQuizResult` entities as base for the form types and build the forms accordingly.

Here is an extract of the two entities to see the mapping definitions:

**UserQuizAnswer**

```
# src/AppBundle/Entity/UserQuizAnswer.php
/**
 * UserQuizAnswer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user__quiz__answer")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserQuizAnswer
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Question
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Question")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var Answer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Answer")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @var UserQuizResult
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserQuizResult", inversedBy="answers")
     */
    private $quizResult;
```

**UserQuizResult**

```
# src/AppBundle/Entity/UserQuizResult.php
/**
 * UserQuizResult
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user__quiz__result")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserQuizResultRepository")
 */
class UserQuizResult
{

    use ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="quizResults")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Quiz
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Quiz", inversedBy="results")
     */
    private $quiz;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserQuizAnswer", mappedBy="quizResult", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $answers;
```

**The following code is an untested example, it is just to give you an idea how you could build your form type classes**

Create a form type `UserQuizAnswerType` referencing the question and rendering the possible answers for that question.

```
# src/AppBundle/Form/UserQuizAnswerType.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Question;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserQuizAnswer;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserQuizAnswerType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /** @var UserQuizAnswer $userQuizAnswer */
        $userQuizAnswer = $builder->getData();

        /** @var Question $question */
        $question = $userQuizAnswer->getQuestion();

        $builder
            ->add('question')
            ->add(
                'answer',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Answer',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use (
                        $question
                    ) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                            ->where('a.question = :question')
                            ->setParameter('question', $question);
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'text',
                ]
            );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserQuizAnswer',
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_userquizanswer';
    }
}
```

To make this work you would need to set the `Question` on the data object passed to the form when creating it, so the form will only show the answers related to that question.

E.g. in your controller:

```
$userQuizAnswer = new UserQuizAnswer();
$userQuizAnswer->setQuestion($question);

$this->createForm(new UserQuizAnswer(), $userQuizAnswer);
```

Create a form type `UserQuizResultType` with a collection of the `UserQuizAnswerType` form types:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
// ...

$builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => UserQuizAnswerType::class,
    'allow_add'  => false
));
```

In your controller you would than need to prepare the data like:

```
/** @var UserQuizResult $userQuizResult */
$userQuizResult = new UserQuizResult();
$userQuizResult->setUser($this->getUser());

/** @var Question $question */
foreach ($quiz->getQuestions() as $question) {
    $userQuizAnswer = new UserQuizAnswer();
    $userQuizAnswer->setQuestion($question);

    // add answer to "collection"
    $userQuizResult->addAnswer($userQuizAnswer);
}

$this->createForm(new UserQuizResult(), $userQuizResult);
```

Comment: What a nice comment ! Thanks a lot @lordrhodos, i've learned a lot !

Comment: @Cesar you are welcome, if that answers your questions you may accept the answer, otherwise please provide some more information how to help exactly.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, I've accepted your answer. It will hopefully help a lot of beginners like me. Thanks !