# How do I persist my form to the database?

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony, persist

I need to persist my form to the database. I am using Symfony to do this and I have built a response entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ResponseRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ResponseRepository::class)
 */
class Response
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @Groups({"response:read"})
     * 
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"response:write", "response:read", "session:read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Session::class, inversedBy="responses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Question::class, inversedBy="responses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"response:read", "response:write"})
     */
    private $question;

    // /**
    //  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=QuestionsQuestionType::class, mappedBy="response")
    //  */
    // private $questionsQuestionType;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->questionsQuestionType = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAnswer(): ?string
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    public function setAnswer(string $answer): self
    {
        $this->answer = $answer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSession(): ?Session
    {
        return $this->session;
    }

    public function setSession(?Session $session): self
    {
        $this->session = $session;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getQuestion(): ?Question
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(?Question $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }
```

A new response function in the ResponseController (please note QuizResponse is an alias of Response entity. This is to not confuse my response entity with Symfony Response) :

```
/**
     * @Route("/new", name="response_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, QuestionRepository $questionRepository): Response
    {
        $questions = $questionRepository->findAll();
        // dd($questions);
        $response = new QuizResponse();
        $form = $this->createForm(ResponseType::class, $response); // problem exists
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($response);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // $formData = $form->getData();
            // dd($formData);
            // echo 'this should work';exit;
            

            return $this->redirectToRoute('response_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('response/new.html.twig', [
            'response' => $response,
            'question' => $questions,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

A ResponseType form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class ResponseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        
        
        
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Response::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my twig template (_form.html.twig):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    

    <div class="mt-3">
    {% for question in question %}
        <input type="hidden" name="response[question][]" value="{{ question.id }}">
        {% set name = 'response[answer]['~ question.id ~']' %}
        {% if question.type == 'checkbox' %}
            {% set name = name ~ '[]' %}
        {% endif %}

        {#    {% if question.replies is defined %}#}
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3 border">
        <h3 class="mb-0" id="question-{{ question.id }}">{{ loop.index }}. {{ question.label }}</h3>
        </div>
        {% if question.type == 'checkbox' or question.type == 'radio' %}
            <div class="answers p-1">
            {% for answer in question.replies %}

                {% set id = 'answer-' ~ answer.id  %}

                <label for="{{ id }}">{{ answer.answer }}</label>
                <input type="{{ question.type }}" name="{{ name }}" id="{{ id }}">
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% elseif question.type == 'textarea' %}
            <textarea name="{{ name }}" aria-labelledby="question-{{ question.id }}" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
        {% elseif question.type == 'number' %}
            <input type="number" name="{{ name }}" aria-labelledby="question-{{ question.id }}">
        {% else %}
            <input type="text" name="{{ name }}" aria-labelledby="question-{{ question.id }}" class="form-control">
        {% endif %}
        {#    {% endif %}#}

    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">{{ button_label|default('Submit') }}</button>
{#{{ form_end(form, {render_rest: false }) }}#}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

It's completely detached from the responseType form which is why I believe it doesn't submit to the database... But I am not sure how to map the ResponseType form to the _form.html.twig

Comment: You need to define your form fields in your `ResponseType` class, in the `buildForm` method, see the example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Field types that you can use for that are listed here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html

Then render the form fields in `_form.html.twig` using `{{ form_widget(form) }}`, see the example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#client-side-html-validation

Comment: Hi Marleen, 

Thanks for your response. 

When I defined my form fields in the ResponseType class, in the buildForm method, it adds additional fields to my form. 

I say this just in case I misinterpreted what you've said, but for example I have built session forms in the way you've stated and they persist perfectly well to the database.

Comment: Should'nt your form *data_class* be `'data_class' => QuizResponse::class,`? Also, i would recommend renaming your Response and QuizResponse to something else as it is confusing and could clash with Symfony's Response class..

Comment: Hi Bossman! 

QuizResponse is the alias as my editor was indeed getting confused between my response entity and symfonys response class. 

'data_class' => Response:class is correct as it doesnt require an alias and that php file isnt getting confused as it doesn't use the symfony response class.

Comment: You would need to add fields to buildForm for the Symfony form system to process/validate incoming form data. If you're trying to generate one Response per Question (but have multiple Responses/Questions on the page), look into Symfony form collections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html You already have a ResponseType for the Response, but you would probably also need a wrapper formtype that holds a collection of those ResponseType objects. This answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44581889/3960296

Comment: Hi Marleen! That's a super helpful answer! My quiz requires that the questions have different answer types. For example. Q1 requires radio button answers for yes or no, Q2 requires multiple choice. Q3 requires text. This is particularly why I'm struggling because I'm not sure how to configure the formtype to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you dont use the form component - you have the class and the correct controller code, but in your template you print the form fields yourself.

Just define the fields in your formType, remove the formfields from your twig and use the supposed `{{ form_*() }}` methods.

To make this conditional rendering of your CollectionType work - you will have to write some twig code in your form theme. (but to explain this is outside of my time and scope of the question)

Comment: Is there a way around using the form component or do I definitely need to use the form component to persist the form?

Comment: use the form component or dont. but it just doesnt make sense to mix it up.